# .bat or .cmd to move all files except first of month

Tags: file, batch-file, command-line, backup

Our backup system is running out of space and we'd like to keep every first backup of the month (creation date) and move the other files to subfolder x.

Is there an easy script for this, as I really have no clue on how to do this.

Comment: Depending on your needs, it might be a very simple script with Robocopy, a command line utility that is part of the system. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx. It copies/moves files and time can be used as one of the filters.

Comment: @MirekE What would the options be for my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET "sourcedir=u:\sourcedir"
SET /a month=99
SET /a year=99
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
FOR /f "skip=4tokens=1,2,3,5,*delims=/- " %%a IN (
  'dir /tc /a-d /-c /od "*" '
  ) DO (
 IF "%%d"=="" GOTO done
 IF %%b-%%c neq !month!-!year! (
  ECHO(leave "%%e" ".\x\" 
  SET month=%%b
  SET year=%%c
 ) ELSE (
  ECHO(MOVE "%%e" ".\x\" 
 )
)
:done
POPD


GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

You don't indicate what your date format and separator are. I use dd/mm/yy. If you use mm/dd/yy then substitute `%%a` for `%%b`  in the action part of the `for` loop (ie. the part ofter the `do`)

The required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

The `/tc` switch on the `dir` statement explicitly selects the `create` date, as requested. This term is often used to be synonymous with last-write date which is the common `date` reported by `dir`. If you actually want last-write date, simply omit the `/tc` switch.

Comment: Thanks for this piece so far. My separator is dd-mm-yyyy.

Comment: can I add a pause or something so I can see why it's not working? The file closes automatically. I've removed the @Echo off, but that's not working.

Comment: Just pop it in on its own line after the `popd`. You could put a `pause` just before the very final close-parenthesis to get a file-by-file readout. You could also extend the `echo(move` and `echo(leave` lines to also report %%b (the month), %%c (the year) !maonth! and !year! (month and year of the previous file). Remember that this procedure will only report what it intends to do and to actually action the move you need to change the `echo(move` to `move` as documented. You can also use `echo on` to get a blow-by-blow description. Unfortunately, "not working" leaves us guessing - exemplify!

Comment: Can you join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/59565/just-now?tab=general for a minute please